# Are there any ODEs like these?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I have been working on using automatic differentiation to compute the sensitivities of systems of ordinary differential equations of the form

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathbf{u}(t)}{dt} = F(\mathbf{u}(t),t,\alpha),\qquad \mathbf{u}(0) = \mathbf{u}^0.
\end{equation}
where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^M$ is a vetor of real valued parameters and $\mathbf{u}(t)\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

To showcase the advantages of the algorithm, I was looking for a real scenario where the vector valued function $F$ depends on a number of parameters $M$ much bigger than the number of equations in the system $N$. By real, I mean some equation  with applicability in any scientific field.

In the article "Neural Ordinary Differential Equations" by Ricky T. Q. Chen, they consider $F$ to be a neural network, where indeed $M \gg N$, but I was looking for an alternative.

What I have considered so far are PDEs discretized in space using finite differences, for example, the 1D heat equation with spatial dependent thermal diffusivity $\alpha(x)$. However, if I consider the set of parameters $\alpha_i = \alpha(x_i)$, where $x_i$ are the grid points, that would result in $M=N$. I could artificially consider more parameters, like $\alpha_{i+\frac{1}{2}} = \alpha(x_{i+\frac{1}{2}})$ and force these on the function $F$, but still I would get $M=2N$, and I don't think it's usual for numerical methods to consider a finer grid for the parameters, rather the other way around  (thinking of FEM for example, where $\alpha(x)$ could possibly be represented by its mean value in the element).

Another thing I have considered is if $F$ depends on some function which needs to be numerically evaluated, and thus would be approximated by a finite set of $M$ parameters ( for example, coefficientes for a given set of basis functions). Can you think of any real example like this where $M \gg N$?

What I really really want is something like $M \approx N^2$ or at least $M \approx kN$ with $k \gg 1$.

Comment: Maybe worth having a look in this compendium : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_differential_equations ?

Comment: I found what I was looking for. The Generalized Lotka Volterra equations are a system of $N$ ODEs with $N+N^2$ parameters, corresponding to the entries of the $\mathbf{r}$ vector and $A$ matrix.